# How do I force a postback on an ASP.NET button inside a jQuery modal dialog (div)?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a modal dialog showing up and the user can make some changes and then click a 'Save' button. I need that to totally post back the whole page. What would you suggest? I just assumed the button would fire off regardless of the jQuery.

Comment: Can you post some of your markup that isn't working?

Do you have an asp:button tag for the save button in your modal dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could force a post back from Javascript:

```
__doPostBack(id,'');
```

To do this directly from a control, like a button, use OnClientClick:

```
<asp:Button id="myButton" runat=server OnClientClick="__doPostBack(id,'');" />
```

Comment: how do I tie that into my ASP.NET button click?

Comment: ?? If you have an asp.net button click then that will already be posting back .....

Comment: @James Westgate: Not necessarily, if you have a declaration like this `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" />` it will generate the following markup `<input type="submit" id="ctl00_cpMainContent_btn1" value="" name="ctl00$cpMainContent$btn1">`.  It looks like jQuery UI dialog basically rips the contents of the dialog out of it's place in the DOM and attaches it as the last element in the body (outside of the form asp.net puts on the page).  Since the button is outside a form, it won't cause a submit.

Comment: you could also check the source of the dialog js, and you should find a line similar to $('body').append(....) and change that to $('form').append(...) so your asp.net button in the dialog remains in the form and can initiate a postback.

Answer (score 3):

put an asp button on the page and hide it with css
in the onclose event of the dialog window, call aspButton.click

```
<asp:button id="myButton" runat="server" OnClick="myButton_Click" style="visible:hidden;" />

...

$('#' + <%= myButton.ClientID %>).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

The basics I use are:

1. Create an ASP button on the page outside of the modal div

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" onclick="hiddenButton_Click" style="visibility:hidden" />`
   ```
2. Assuming you have the Save button already in your modal div, call the button click event in JavaScript(this was taken from a jQuery dialog event):

   ```
   buttons: {
       Save: function () {
           $(this).dialog('close');
           $("#<%=hiddenButton.ClientID %>").click();
       }
   }
   ```